# Odoo 13, Access right for model as readonly but selectable inside relational model

Tags: odoo

There is model1 that has many2many relation with model2. inside model1's form there is a tree of model2

I want user add lines inside form of model1 but user should not be able to create new record in model2.

I set access right to 1,0,0,0 for user but he can't now add or delete any lines.

Answer (score 0):

you set diferent access to model1 and model2 like this?

```
access_module_name_model1,module_name.model1,model_module_name_model1,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
access_module_name_model2,module_name.model2,model_module_name_model2,base.group_user,1,0,0,0
```